# Quotient space and quotient map

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, quotient-spaces

Let $X:= [-2,2]$ a topological space with the canonical topology and let $A:=[-1,1]\subset X$ and $f:X \rightarrow X/A$ the quotient map.

How can I find an explicit form of the quotient space $X/A$?

And is $X$ a compact space? (I only know that it is complete, but I don't know if it is also compact)

Have someone any suggestions please? Thanks!

Comment: It should look like the interval $[-1, 1] \cong [-2, 2]/[-1, 1]$ the equivalence class of $[-1, 1]$ in the original space corresponding to the point $0\in[-1, 1]\cong [-2, 2]/[-1, 1]$.

Comment: If ${(U_i)}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of your quotient space then the collection ${(\pi^{-1}(U_i))}_{i\in I}$ is an open cover of the total space. If the total space is compact the cover ${(\pi^{-1}(U_i))}_{i\in I}$ has a finite subcover and then passing back the quotient you obtain a finite subcover of the original open cover.

Comment: I think you must have meant to ask whether $X/A$ is compact.  And it is because any continuous image of the compact space $X$ is compact.

Comment: In case you really meant to ask whether $X$ itself is compact, you should learn the Heine-Borel theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient of a compact space is always compact, as $q: X \to X / \sim$ is always continuous (where $q$ is the standard quotient map), and images of compact spaces are compact.

In your case the function $f: X=[-2,2] \to [-1,1]$ where $f(x) = x+1$ for $x\in [-2,-1]$, $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in [-1,1]$ and $f(x) = x-1$ for $x \in [1,2]$ is continuous and obeys $f(x) = f(y)$ iff $x \sim y$ in the equivalence relation determined by identifying $A$ to a point.

A standard theorem then implies that $X/A = X / \sim \simeq f[X] = [-1,1]$.

Comment: Why did you choose the function $f$ of this form? And why is $X/A=[−1:1]$ of this form?

Comment: See @Velvet’s comment on the question. We just squeeze a closed interval to $0$ in the middle and scale the rest along.